# Checksum библиотека под Android

Tags: android

Делаю небольшое приложение для конвертации различных типов строковых данных, + вычисление контрольной суммы. Предполагается CRC (8-64), SHA (0-512), Tiger (1-160) Adler32 и т.д. 
Есть ли какая-то библиотека для Android, которая могла бы вычислять хэши? Типа jacksum, только для Android. На Гите нашёл только это:
https://github.com/PaulMEdwards/DroidSum
Но она не обновлялась уже 5 лет, да и документации вообще никакой нет.
В принципе, можно написать все самому, но может быть есть хорошее стороннее решение?